Does laser treatment on face affect wudhu as it leaves a small laser layer on skin for days. Does it invalidate wudhu?
Does laser treatment on face affect wudhu as it leaves a small laser layer on skin for days. Does it invalidate wudhu ?

No, laser treatment does not affect wudhoo, as it does not literally cover the skin. It is permissible. What is required for wudhoo is that the face is fully washed, which refers to the skin itself. If a part of the skin remains dry and is visible, that area must be washed.
This indicates that if any visible part of the face (or body) remains dry, the wudhoo is invalidated, and it must be repeated before performing the prayer. Prayer must be repeated as well.
The full hadith is narrated in Sunan Abu Dawood:

The Prophet (peace and blessings be upon him) saw a man who had a
small portion of his foot that was not washed during wudhoo, about the
size of a coin. The Prophet (peace be upon him) then instructed him
to repeat his wudhoo and prayer. (SHaikh Al Bani, Saheeh Sunan Abi Dawood no. 161. Recorded by Abu Dawud)

In light of this, if any part of the face is not washed, as seen, it is obligatory to repeat both the wudhoo and the prayer, starting the sequence again from the beginning. He should not take doubt into action, unless he is more certain.
